# Grammatical structure of "upon"

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

What is the grammatical role and structure of "upon" in the following sentences?

> Much of the world’s great architecture has been constructed of stone
>   because of its beauty, permanence, and availability. In the past,
>   whole cities grew from the arduous task of cutting and piling stone
>   **upon**.

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Comment: Are you sure that the sentence does not end with "piling stone upon stone" instead of "piling stone upon"?

Comment: @Jasper Yes, I am sure. But it may be the wrong in the source as @ fred2 has answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a Google search and [found the phrase you cited here](https://www.ibtil.org/ckfinder/userfiles/files/NEWW%20PRE-TOEFL%20Reading.pdf). Obviously, it is being used in a "TOEFL" course.

Despite the fact the sentence was presumably written by an expert in English, I think the use of "upon" in the sentence is clearly an error which was missed by the proof-readers. "Upon" could and should either be omitted entirely, or one needs to say *upon what* the stone is being piled.